# React-router force querystring to be an array with a single element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I just migrated an app made with `react` and `react-router` from an old version to `react 0.15` and `react-router 2.0`

In the old version the `Links` where created like this:

```
<Link to='route-name' query={{ids: [1]}}>
  {name}
</Link>
```

This constructed a url like `/route/?ids[]=1`. That would give me in the component

```
this.props.query = {
  ids: ['1']
}
```

After the upgrade the `Link` declaration was changed to:

```
<Link to={{pathname:`/route/`, query={ids: [1]}}}>
  {name}
</Link>
```

Which produces urls like `/route/ids=1`, now the Router parses the querystring like this:

```
this.props.location.query = {
  ids : '1'
}
```

The only way I've managed to get an array if is the array in the link declaration has more than one element, although the url doesn't use empty brackets in the url.

So is there a way to force the router to use an array when there is only a single element, I don't want to have to check every time if what I'm getting is an array or a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in the [history docs](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/83f1a6382bd03b04d334958f44be6c9362b920a5/docs/QuerySupport.md#query-support), you need to use a [custom history](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-custom-histories) that parses the querystrings like you need it.

React-router uses the `query-string` package for the parse and stringify functions, doing a quick glance of the code I don't think it supports your use case, fortunately the `qs` package does it with just setting an options.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
import { stringify, parse } from 'qs'
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

const stringifyQuery = query => stringify(query, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' })
const history = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({ parseQueryString: parse, stringifyQuery })

<Router history={history} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) package.

```
import { stringify } from 'qs';

var queryStr = stringify({ ids: [21] }, { encode: false });
```

Comment: Thanks David, but not found... :(

Comment: The qs package gives you the string url, but the thing is that react-router parses the url and returns a string instead of an Array in the query object.